# How to disply "12000" as "120.00" numeric value?

Tags: javascript

I get a string, something like "Value: $ 120.00", so I use this to convert the string to a numeric value:

```
let price = "Value: $ 120.00"
price = Number(price.replace(/\D/g, ''));
```

but this returns 12000, and i need display 120.00, such as numeric value.

Comment: Use `[^\d.]` instead of `\D`. But note that you'll get `120`, not `120.00`. Well, you'll get both, really; `120` is precisely equal to `120.00`. You can format the resulting number however you want of course.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Do you need the g parameter? to apply to all string (every string will have more than one price?)

```js
let price = "Value: $ 120.00";
price = /(\d+).(\d+)/.exec("Value: $ 120.00");
console.log(price[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const price = "Value: $ 120.00".replace(/[^\d|\.]/g,'')

console.log(price)
```